# I cannot define tikz coordinate with foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, coordinates

I got a weird bug when I want to define and name a list of coordinates

```
\tikz{
\foreach \name/\pos in {{a/(1,0)}, {b/(0,1)}} 
  \coordinate (\name) at \pos ;
}
```

The error is

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3]
Runaway argument?
 \pos ;\pgffor@endhook \ifx \pgffor@assign@after@code \pgfutil@empty \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@@coordinate@@at was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.44
```

The manual expansion of the list works. I can also use foreach with the following syntax which seems to me less natural

```
\tikz{
      \foreach \name/\pos in {{a/(1,0)}, {b/(0,1)}} 
      \draw \pos node (\name) {\name};
      \draw (a)--(b);
}
```

A full example with swapped variables does not work either.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes, arrows, decorations.markings, calc, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \pos/\name in {{(1,0)}/a, {(0,1)}/b}
      \coordinate (\name) at \pos;
    \draw (a)--(b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Swap the variables: `\pos/\name in {(1,0)/a, …}`. The `,` in the coordinate is tripping you up. If the entry starts with `(` special parsing is activated. Alternatively, put the coordinate in braces, i.e. `a/{(1,0)}`. Your workaround does similar things but on a broader scope.

Comment: Please provide complete code to reproduce the error you show. (Generally - I think you have an answer here already.)

Comment: your code works well! Please update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Ah, I think I've missed something with my first comment – didn't notice the braces in the first code. But @BlackMild is correct. With an uptodate TikZ, this shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, a workaround might be `\coordinate[at/.expanded=\pos](\name);`.